# Display JTable in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jlabel

I've been trying to add JTable to my JPanel, yet it doesn't appear there. I've searched through other questions, but solutions proposed there didn't help me.

The function below is a part of a class which extends JFrame. "repaint" is a BufferedImage, "imageLabel" is JLabel and "image" is ImageIcon.

```
public void showTable() {
    try {
        repaint = ImageIO.read(new File("filename.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    Graphics g = repaint.createGraphics();
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(black);
    String[] columnsName = {"id","text"};
    Object[][] data = {{new Integer(1),"text one"},{new Integer(2),"text two"}};
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnsName);
    JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);
    image = new ImageIcon(repaint.getScaledInstance(sizeX,sizeY, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    imageLabel.setIcon(image);
    imageLabel.add(tableContainer,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(imageLabel);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

What I want to achieve is to display table over loaded image.

Thanks in advance for Your help :)

Comment: Did you set the layout manager for `imageLabel`? JLabel defaults to null layout. We need to set it if we want to add components to it

Comment: Why are you trying to put everything inside a `JLabel`?

Comment: You're doing many things wrong -- not using a layout manager, expecting `BorderLayout.CENTER` constant to work if the container doesn't yet use BorderLayout, getting your Graphics object via `getGraphics()`... time to start reading the tutorials as it beats guessing every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you want to put a table and an image below it, right?
I would create a JPanel with BorderLayout, put the image (JLabel) on the bottom (Page end) and the table (that scrollPanel you created) on the center.
If you need help with adding items to JPanel with BorderLayout, see how to do it on this Tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Give your JLabel a layout manager, here BorderLayout via `setLayout(new BorderLayout())`.
2. Don't get your Graphics object via `getGraphics()` as it returns an object that is short-lived. To see for yourself, minimize your program and then restore it and watch your drawing disappear. Instead, draw in the `paintComponent(...)` override method.
3. Read the Swing tutorials for greater detail on how to do these things, especially the layout manager tutorial.

Comment: Scratching my head. Your answer is completely different from the accepted answer. You answer assumes the OP wants the label to be a background, which is what I assumed (The code kind of sugggests that). The accepted answer suggests something totally different. Who knows :/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the hints so far :) They were really useful. I know that I might be doing some things in a not elegant way, but I'm still learning, will try to improve :)

The given hints and some more searching lead me to such code :

```
    public void showTable()
    {
    try
    {
        repaint = ImageIO.read(new File("filename.jpg"));
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }
    Graphics g = repaint.createGraphics();
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(black);
    String[] columnsName = {"id","text"};
    Object[][] data = {{new Integer(1),"text one"},{new Integer(2),"text two"}};
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnsName);
    table.setOpaque(false);
    JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);
    tableContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    tableContainer.setOpaque(false);
    tableContainer.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    image = new ImageIcon(repaint.getScaledInstance(sizeX,sizeY, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    imageLabel.setIcon(image);
    imageLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    imageLabel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    }
```

Which works fine for me :)

Once again thanks all for the help :)